# How to do Azure Ad authentication in AWS Lambda?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, azure-active-directory

Hi I am working as below. I have postman which is used to generate JWT token(Registered app in azure ad) and use token with API. API will call AWS API Gateway with token. Now I generated JWT token. I am sending with each API. Now I want to validate this token. I want to use AWS lambda. I am not sure what kind of template I should pick for this purpose? Also I am not finding any better examples to validate template. Can someone help me to start this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
Below is my postman to get access token.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure AD REST API and consider it as an external app that needs to get a token from Azure AD in order to have its requests authorized.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

I'm not aware of any existing samples, and the only official documentation that I've seen on AWS Azure integration is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/amazon-web-service-tutorial).

Comment: I believe the question is the inverse of this @Marilee. The application receives a user's Azure token - it has the token already - it doesn't need to get it's requests authorized, it needs to validate the token that it's getting.